# Expected "(" (_): At line 939 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ZYXEL-ES2108G-MIB.txt

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib

Got an error while running snmptranslate -IR sysSwYear

***Expected "(" (_): At line 939 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ZYXEL-ES2108G-MIB.txt
Should be ACCESS (to): At line 939 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ZYXEL-ES2108G-MIB.txt
Bad parse of OBJECT-TYPE: At line 939 in /usr/share/snmp/mibs/ZYXEL-ES2108G-MIB.txt
Unknown object identifier: sysSwYear....***

What is the reason behind it???please help me

Comment: Maybe try asking at serverfault.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace "_" with "-" and it work's fine :D

Comment: @bzyk667....Thanks man ,because of your answer only I am able to solve the problem...Once again Thanks Alot

Answer (score 5):

Use -Pu flag.

-Pu    Toggles whether to allow the underline character in MIB object names and other symbols.  Strictly speaking, this is not valid SMI  syntax,  but  some  vendor  MIB  files
              define such names.  The default behaviour can also be set with the configuration token mibAllowUnderline.